# Multiple CBPeripheral's for same device

Tags: ios, events, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When using the CoreBluetooth framework to access Bluetooth Low Energy devices, the [`CBCentralManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html) returns a [`CBPeripheral`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/translated_content/CBPeripheral.html) for the peripheral.

Multiple services are available on the peripheral and I would like to split the code that handles characteristic value updates for the different services into multiple classes. Therefore, I would need to attach multiple `id<CBPeripheralDelegate>` delegates to the peripheral. However, this is not possible because only one delegate is supported.

- Is there a way to get multiple `CBPeripheral` instances for the same peripheral?

  *If it is possible that multiple applications access the same peripheral, do they receive different `CBPeripheral` instances? If yes, do they see updates from the other application? (Say, application A writes a value to a characteristic, does application B's delegate also receive the [– peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:] message?)*
- Are there any elegant approaches to support splitting the event handling code into multiple classes?

Answer (score 4):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906146/774) for [CoreBluetooth: How to design code for many characteristics (30 - 40)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897304/corebluetooth-how-to-design-code-for-many-characteristics-30-40) has some design tips that may be helpful here. In short, create a mediating class that can be a `CBPeripheralDelegate` and supports multiple characteristic classes registering for whatever characteristic they desire.